# ggplot2: Make the filled area of the spatial plot flush with facet strip

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the following ggplot command

```
p <- ggplot(blc.df,aes(x=long,y=lat, group=group,fill=act.exp))+
  geom_polygon()+
  facet_wrap(~hour,ncol=6, labeller = as_labeller(df.names))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(limits = c(min(blc.df$act.exp),max(blc.df$act.exp)), colours=pal(100), 
                       breaks=c(min(blc.df$act.exp), ceiling(min(blc.df$act.exp)):floor(max(blc.df$act.exp)), max(blc.df$act.exp)),
                       labels=round(10^c(min(blc.df$act.exp), ceiling(min(blc.df$act.exp)):floor(max(blc.df$act.exp)), max(blc.df$act.exp))),
                       guide = guide_colorbar(title = "ug/m3-hr",title.position = "right", 
                      barwidth = 50, draw.ulim = TRUE, draw.llim = TRUE))+
  coord_equal(ratio=(min(blc.df$lat)-max(blc.df$lat))/(min(blc.df$long)-max(blc.df$long)))+
  xlim(min(blc.df$long), max(blc.df$long))+
  ylim(min(blc.df$lat), max(blc.df$lat))+
  labs(x="",y="")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "lines"),
        panel.border = element_rect(linetype = "dashed", colour = "black"),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        legend.position="bottom",
        legend.direction="horizontal")
print(p)
ggsave("exp3.jpeg", height = 13, width=16 )
```

to create a plot that looks like this
[image]

As you can see, for some reason, each individual spatial plot leaves some margin on all the 4 edges. I just need the filled polygon plot to be flush with the border (or at least, as close as I can possibly get). I tried the plot.margin to no avail (although, it appears plot.margin acts on the entire plot instead of a single panel). I tried defining the xlim and ylim values to no avail. Any ideas how to fix this?

If you need it here is the link for the [folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nrsa49k3t9z8k6x/AAD_SLeddXOWq9YDpEpoWi2Ca?dl=0) containing the spatial file and the dataset and below is the initial code that sets up the ggplot parameters.

```
    require(ggplot2)
    require(data.table)
    require(maptools)

    color.palette       <- function(steps, n.steps.between=NULL, ...){
      if (is.null(n.steps.between)) n.steps.between <- rep(0, (length(steps) - 1))
      if (length(n.steps.between) != length(steps) - 1) stop("Must have one less n.steps.between value than steps")

      fill.steps  <- cumsum(rep(1, length(steps)) + c(0,n.steps.between))
      RGB <- matrix(NA, nrow = 3, ncol = fill.steps[length(fill.steps)])
      RGB[,fill.steps] <- col2rgb(steps)

      for (i in which(n.steps.between > 0)) {
        col.start = RGB[,fill.steps[i]]
        col.end = RGB[,fill.steps[i + 1]]
        for (j in seq(3)) {
          vals <- seq(col.start[j], col.end[j], length.out = n.steps.between[i] + 2)[2:(2 + n.steps.between[i] - 1)]
          RGB[j,(fill.steps[i] + 1):(fill.steps[i + 1] - 1)] <- vals
        }
      }

      new.steps   <- rgb(RGB[1,], RGB[2,], RGB[3,], maxColorValue = 255)
      pal         <- colorRampPalette(new.steps, ...)
      return(pal)
    }
    steps               <- c("blue", "cyan", "yellow", "red")
    pal                 <- color.palette(steps, space = "Lab")

    load("spatemp.exposure1.RData")
    blckgrp <- readShapePoly("blockgroup_utm.shp")
    proj4string(blckgrp) <- CRS("+init=epsg:32617")

    blckgrp <- blckgrp[which(blckgrp@data$COUNTYFP=="057" & blckgrp@data$GEOID!="120579901000" & blckgrp@data$GEOID!="120579802001" & blckgrp@data$GEOID!="120579900000"),]

    blc.data <- data.frame(id=rownames(blckgrp@data),GEOID=blckgrp@data$GEOID)
    blc.data <- merge(blc.data,spatemp.exposure1[,.(hour, GEOID, act.exp)])
    blc.df   <- fortify(blckgrp)
    blc.df   <- merge(blc.df,blc.data)

    blc.df$fac <- ifelse(blc.df$hour==1, paste0(blc.df$hour+11, " - ", blc.df$hour, " am"), ifelse((blc.df$hour>1 & blc.df$hour<12), paste0(blc.df$hour-1, " - ", blc.df$hour, " am"),
                        ifelse(blc.df$hour==12, paste0(blc.df$hour-1, " am - ", blc.df$hour, " pm"), ifelse(blc.df$hour==13, paste0(blc.df$hour-1, " - ", blc.df$hour-12, " pm"),
                        ifelse((blc.df$hour>13 & blc.df$hour<24), paste0(blc.df$hour-13, " - ", blc.df$hour-12, " pm"), paste0(blc.df$hour-13, " pm - ", blc.df$hour-12, " am"))))))

    df.names <- rbind(unique(blc.df$hour), unique(blc.df$fac))
    colnames(df.names) <- df.names[1,]
    df.names <- df.names[-1,]
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/25693449/6455166.

Comment: Wow...that does the trick..and here I am doing all kinds of stuff from yesterday :(

Comment: Or replace `coord_equal` with `coor_fixed(expand = FALSE)`.